# How to implement a sticky header on mobile devices

Tags: arrays, scroll, mobile-safari, sticky

I know how to implement a sticky header on PC browser. However, on mobile devices, 'scroll' event behaves really weired. It only fires once after window stopped scrolling, so that I cannot monitor 'window.scrollTop' in real time.

I also tried 'position:sticky', but this only supported on IOS8 and above.

so what is the right way to create a sticky header on mobile browsers? Any ideas are appreciate, thank you~

Answer (score -1):

You can use framework like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) to easily achieve that.
Here is code snippet for the same.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question, if you have first sticky row, then you have no problem. But if sticky header need to be fixed in any momen after scrolling. Then it appears with the delay.